# Building a background app with audio and location services

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, geolocation

I'm building an app that is location-aware and triggers text to speech whenever the user gets near a certain point. I have singleton classes `GPSManager` (for getting location updates) and `RouteDetails` (for defining the points that should trigger the text-to-speech). I also have a view controller that shows a map updating the user's location from `GPSManager` and showing a route from `RouteDetails`.

What I want to do is keep the functionality of the view controller running when the app is suspended, i.e. be notified when the location is updated, compare it to the locations in `RouteDetails`, and then play the text-to-speech. However I can't seem to find a good example of this being done - how do I made sure `RouteDetails` and `GPSManager` stay in memory? And where should I put the text-to-speech module where it can access the details in `RouteDetails` and also be in memory so that it can play when the app is suspended and the phone is locked? I'm assuming the view controller can't receive notifications when the app is suspended.

Also, I've added the `location` and `audio` options to the `UIBackgroundModes` key in the Info.plist file. And I don't need the app to bring itself back into the foreground when it gets a location update/plays a sound, it just needs to play a sound and update a variable in `RouteDetails`.

Comment: From what you described your app should already work in the background, right ? I only have doubts you need to enable an `audio` background mode - if your location manager has been started to update users location and the app was moved to background, it will not be suspended until the location manager is stopped with the `location` background mode. Unfortunately, I don't have enough experience to tell you when the app resources might be unloaded in the background (not suspended) mode.